# Identify value with its matched control

Tags: r

I have this data frame:

```
w$disease<-c(1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0)
w$location<-c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","A","B","B","C","C","D", "D","D","D","A","D","A","D")
w$date<-c("2010-01-01","2010-01-01","2010-05-01","2010-05-01","2010-07-01","2010-07-01","2010-07-01","2010-07-01","2010-08-02","2010-08-02","2010-08-07","2010-08-07","2010-08-07","2010-08-07","2010-08-07","2010-08-09","2010-10-02","2010-10-02","2011-01-15","2011-01-15","2011-02-14","2011-02-14","2012-07-14","2011-07-14","2012-01-02","2012-01-02","2012-01-02","2012-01-02")
```

I want to order w so that than m fits the data as follows

```
w$m<-c(1,1,2,2,3,4,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,6,7,8,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,14,13,14)
```

where

```
     w[1]  is 1 A "2010-01-01" and w$m[1]  is  1,
then w[2]  is 0 A "2010-01-01" and w$m[2]  is  1,
     w[28] is 0 D "2012-01-02" and w$m[28] is 14
```

This is what I wrote

```
w$pd<-do.call(paste, c(w[c("date","location")], sep=" "))
w<-w[order(w$pd),]
j<-1
m<-1
for(i in 1:length(w$disease)){
  if(w$disease[i]==1){
    m[i]<-j
    j<-ifelse(w$d[i+1]==0,j+1,1)
  }else{
    m[i]<-j
    j<-ifelse(w$d[i+1]==1,j+1,j)
 }
}
```

This works until I get the to the stage where there is a 1,1 or a 0,0 instance. Hope this is any clerer. Any idea?
Many thanks,
Marco

Comment: What is the rule (in words) that you wish to follow to generate this vector? I don't see the pattern between the input and output. What does `w$t` have to do with it? What do you mean by "this vector fits"?

Comment: Ok I have not explained it very well and by trying to simplify I have made it less clear. So w$d is 1=disease and 0=control, w$p is a factor and identifies the location the data has been obtained from and w$t was actually the date the data was collected. I am trying to define a variable that matches each disease patient to its control (controls are matched to disease by practice and date). I had initially tried simply to order the data by location and date but multiple disease cases could be from the same location and some control had a date of the following day and it did not work

Comment: When you add additional information like this, it's best to edit the original question than put important details in comments. Also, why do you need your cases/controls to alternate rows? Are you using a function that requires it? If you have 2 cases (A,B) and 2 controls (X,Y) for a given combo does it matter who gets paired with whom (A-X, B-Y vs A-Y, B-X)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC (just by looking at your answer), using `ave` - inbuilt function that comes with R:

```
w$m <- with(w, ave(disease, disease, FUN=seq_along))
> w$m
# [1]  1  1  2  2  3  4  3  4  5  5  6  7  8  6  7  8  9  9 10 10 11 11 12 12 13 14 13 14
```

---

Another way:

Using `data.table` (an external package), that you can install using:

```
# installation can be done by
install.packages("data.table")

## load the package
require(data.table) ## 1.9.2
setDT(w)[, m := 1:.N, by=disease]
```

`.N` is a special variable that contains the number of elements per group (here `disease`). `setDT` converts your `data.frame` to `data.table`.

---

Edit: if `setDT` doesn't work, run `update.packages("data.table")` in console and try again

Comment: This might seem silly but I can not load the library base even though I am using R 3.0.2. Why is this?

Comment: @MarcoD - base isn't a package, Arun is just referring to the `ave` function included in R itself.

Comment: Thank you. This does what it is meant to, however there is something wrong in my data and it worked until one point there one case is missing a match completely and after that the w$m values are all over the place. I need to figure out what is wrong with my data first. Cheers

Comment: @Arun you mentioned require(data.table) ## 1.9.2+
setDT(w)[, set := 1:.N, by=disease] but I can not find setDT in data.table library - am  I missing something? What does this do?

Comment: @MarcoD, update your `data.table` package version by doing `update.packages("data.table")`

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
  w%>% 
  group_by(disease) %>%
  mutate(n=row_number())%>%
  subset(select=n, drop=TRUE)
 #[1]  1  1  2  2  3  4  3  4  5  5  6  7  8  6  7  8  9  9 10 10 11 11 12 12 13
#[26] 14 13 14
```